# An $RO$-group which is not $O$-group

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

I was thinking of some example for an Right ordered group ( $RO$-group) which is not an $O-$group (Ordered group) i.e. not left ordered.

I guess looking in matrix groups will be fruitful but how to define an ordering on matrices , say $GL_n{(\mathbb{R})}$. Now $\mathbb{Z}$ has an ordering '$<$', then if I say $A<'B \iff det(A)<det(B)$,  <' is not an ordering on group of matrices as  $A<'B$ does not imply $ CA <'CB $ when det($C$) = $-1$.

Suggest some ordering on matrices or some other example of some $RO$ group which is not ordered.

Comment: A general linear group won't work, because a right-ordered group needs to be torsion free.

Comment: I think the class of right orderable groups is closed under extension, so the example I proposed earlier of a solvable group that cannot be ordered can be right orderable.

Comment: Yes derek, thanks for reminding me. It is a very useful example. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302105/can-every-torsion-free-nilpotent-group-be-ordered) is the link of that example you talked about, for some other users that might be interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from Kopytov and Medvedev, *Right-Ordered Groups*, which they attribute to Smirnov:

Consider the group of 2×2 matrices of the form $[{}^k_0\,{}^a_1]$ where $k$ is a positive rational and $a$ is a rational. The group operations work out to
$$ (k_1,a_1)*(k_2,a_2) = (k_1k_2, a_1+k_1a_2) \qquad\quad (k,a)^{-1} = (1/k,-a/k) \qquad\quad e = (1,0)$$
(One might observe that this is a semidirect product $\mathbb Q_{>0}^{\times}\rtimes \mathbb Q^+$).

Choose a fixed irrational number $\varepsilon$ and define $(k,a)>e$ iff $k+a\varepsilon > 1$. One easily sees that for every $g\ne e$, exactly one of $g>e$ and $g^{-1}>e$ holds, so this extends uniquely to a right order
$$ (k_1,a_1) > (k_2,a_2) \iff k_1+k_2a_1\varepsilon > k_2+k_1a_2\varepsilon $$
However, this is not a left order. For example, if $\frac13<\varepsilon<\frac12$ then we have
$$ (1,1) < (2,0) $$
but
$$ (1,1)*(1,1) = (1,2) > (1,1)*(2,0) = (2,1) $$

Comment: But  I think that it should be $\frac13<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}$, for this to be valid. Can you double check, my calculations are telling me this.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Whoops, that's what my notes say, too. Fixed.

Comment: It is nice to know there is a whole book on RO groups. It is costly to purchase for me right now, but some day.

Comment: Can we define a similar ordering on this group which makes it Left orderable but not right orderable? I was trying but did not get anywhere.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Yes, once you have a concept of $g>e$ such that (a) $g_1>e$ and $g_2>e$ imply $g_1g_2>e$, and (b) when $g\ne e$, exactly one of $g>e$ and $g^{-1}>e$ is true, then you can extend that uniquely to a right ordering by defining $g_1>g_2$ to mean $g_1g_2^{-1}>e$ (which is what happens above), **or** to a left ordering by defining $g_1>g_2$ to mean $g_2^{-1}g_1>e$.